# Hostname and IP address mapping in /etc/hosts

Tags: ip, hostname

In my linux machine, when I run `hostname`, it shows `mongodb`, but when I run `host mongodb`, it shows:

```
mongodb@mongodb:/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ host mongodb
Host mongodb not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
192.168.10.10   mongodb
192.168.10.10   localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

- My first question is: Since `/etc/hosts` is mapping from IP to hostname, why this machine cannot resolve the hostname `mongodb` to IP 192.168.10.10? Instead, when I run `host localhost`, it can be resolved and shows:

  ```
  localhost has address 127.0.0.1
  ```
- My another question: According to the `/etc/hosts` file, the hostname `localhost` should have been resolved to 192.168.10.10 instead of loopback IP address 127.0.0.1. Anybody can explain this to me?

Answer (score 32):

The `host` (and `nslookup`) utilities explicitly query DNS servers, and do not consult the `/etc/hosts` file in a default system configuration.  If you were to `traceroute` or `ping` that address, you would see it correctly resolve.

You do **not** want to change `localhost` to map to anything other than 127.0.0.1! This can have strange and subtle effects on many things.  I *think* that `/etc/hosts` is parsed in the order in which it is written, and since you have:

```
192.168.10.10   localhost    # do NOT do this!
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

... the second entry may be overriding the first.

Comment: You answer really confused me.On one hand ,you said that /etc/hosts has no effect on the output of command host,but then you said the later line override the previous one in /etc/hosts.So , what on earch does the /etc/hosts affect the output of command 'host'?

Comment: `/etc/hosts` does not have *any* effect on DNS resolution when querying DNS servers directly, which is what `host` does.  However, many system tools and utilities *use* the `localhost` definition, expecting it to be a loopback address, and use system name resolution (which looks at `/etc/hosts` before querying DNS) to resolve names rather than strictly going to DNS, which may not always be present.

Comment: I can also share experience with problems in the `/etc/hosts` file regarding `localhost`.  In the past we had used some software that would insert a `127.0.0.2    localhost` in the hosts file and with that being the last `localhost` entry causing it to be the one in effect caused all kinds of software and license problems.  So my recommendation is to have `127.0.0.1   localhost` as the first entry in your `/etc/hosts` file and make sure there is no other `localhost` entry in that file.  And I would also verify any ipv6 stuff as well.

Comment: To be somewhat pedantic, both do a ns lookup which *might* be a dns lookup if that is how you have configured the host lookup in nsswitch.conf.

Comment: @symcbean - what you say is correct. I wouldn't call that pedantic.

Comment: A notable non-obvious exception to this is if your `/etc/resolv.conf` points to a DNS server running directly on your device (like a caching `dnsmasq`) and said server is consulting your local `/etc/hosts` before querying external servers. Then, indirectly, commands like `host` will be effected by your `/etc/hosts` - this is an uncommon setup, but one I have seen devices ship with, and experience of someone using such a system can seem to conflict with this answer if someone is unaware of this peculiar setup.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to DopeGhoti's answer, to test your resolving, inlcuding the `/etc/hosts` precedence, you can use the `getent hosts <some_hostname>` command.

Answer (score -3):

I got similar issues with a /etc/hosts containing multiple spaces between IP and hostname, instead using a TAB. After changing to TAB the hostname could be resolved by ping.

```
127.0.0.1        test.local
         ^^^^^^^^ → Should be a TAB not multiple spaces.
```

see also on https://superuser.com/a/938366/467479

Comment: This surprises me.  The manpage for `hosts` says: `Fields of the entry are separated by any number of blanks and/or tab characters.`  Perhaps in your case there was some extraneous non-printable character between the IP and the hostname?

Comment: There weren't definitively no non-printable characters. I checked this before I posted this here ;)

Comment: I don't have tab characters, I run SLES 11.x, and after clean installation from dvd my /etc/hosts file has `127.0.0.1` followed by 7 spaces followed by `localhost`.  So i would be a little hesitant to pin the problem specifically on multiple space characters and concluding using the tab character as the solution.

Comment: forgot to mention the tab versus space may also happen within a specific version or distribution of linux, which may be a bug?  and if this were the case you should be able to make various ip address / hostname entries with either a tab or a space, then do a ping on them to see if it gets resolved... just don't do it with `localhost`

Comment: unfortunately I don't remember on which machine (and therefore distro) I experienced the problem... - I think it was on Ubuntu 15.05 from https://virtualboximages.com/Ubuntu+15.05+VDI+VirtualBox+Virtual+Computer
I am going to evaluate that.