# Can't resolve hostname on Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Using Digital Ocean for a webhost, I setup 2 droplets, prod.domain.com, dev.domain.com.

Where I manage the domain through Digital Ocean, I created 2 different A records (dev/prod) pointing them to the respective droplet IPs.

Using dev as example, I set the hostname of the server:

```
hostname dev.domain.com
```

Then modified the /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.1.1       dev.domain.com dev
```

Through my registrar, I pointed nameservers to Digital Ocean NS1,NS2,NS3.digitalocean.com

I can ping via IP, but not hostname. Records are propagated.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: The `hosts` file will be checked before an actual DNS inquiry is made.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109247/20246

Comment: Where are you pinging from - the host itself or some other machine "out there"? What evidence do you have that the relevant DNS records have been completely propagated? (Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/458704/edit) as if you'd thought of these questions - and their answers - yourself, so that they're easily readably by others. Don't respond here in comments.)

Comment: The entries probably haven't propagated to other DNS servers yet. You'll likely have to just wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dig` is installed, you could try querying their name servers directly, tracing the request using

```
dig +trace @ns1.digitalocean.com dev.example.com
```

If `dig` isn't available, you can try to use the `nslookup` command

```
nslookup -debug dev.example.com ns1.digitalocean.com
```